# Is it possible for a quadratic to have only one root, and not touch the $x$-axis?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, graphing-functions

Is it possible for a quadratic to have only one root, but its graph crosses the $x$-axis rather than simply touching it?

Comment: If it has only one real root, this root must be a double root hence the graph must touch the $x$-axis.

Comment: No.  Given $ax^2+bx+c=0$, there are exactly three possibilities, distinguished by the value of $\Delta = b^2-4ac$: two real roots (if $\Delta > 0$), zero real roots (if $\Delta < 0$), or one real root "by touching" (if $\Delta=0$).

Comment: If a quadratic has only one root, then it is of the form $y=a(x-c)^2$, where $a\neq0$. If $a$ is positive, then the quadratic is always positive or $0$, so it can't cross the $x$-axis (if it crossed the $x$-axis, then it would the quadratic would take negative values, which is impossible). Similarly, if $a$ is negative, then the quadratic is always negative or $0$, so again it can't cross the $x$-axis.

Comment: @Joe i think the OP means to say can a quadratic have a graph like this https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pcszcbmc8j

Comment: @Ercanayan: It was me who edited the question. I edited it again. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: @Joe Yes thanks, The answer to this question as far as i can think is NO, as the quadratic cannot have a point of inflection to match the situation the OP has asked. Do you agree? For a quadratic, the graph is always monotonous concave up/down.

Comment: @Ercanayan: Yes, I agree. To be precise: if a quadratic has only root, then it cannot take both positive and negative values. This means that the quadratic cannot "cross" the $x$-axis, e.g. by having a point of inflection there.

Comment: Not voting to close since it is an OK question even though the OP shows no work. Provided a community wiki answer so it doesn't stay open.

Comment: With all said, the _quadratic_ must be defined as a graph of a function of the form $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ for $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$ **and** $a\ne 0$. If you for any reason allow $a=0$, then $f(x)=bx+c$ is a _linear_ function, which surely can have a single root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The comments offer many reasons. Here's one from @Joe

> If a quadratic has only one root, then it is of the form
> $=(−)^2$, where $≠0$. If $$ is positive, then the
> quadratic is always positive or $0$, so it can't cross the $$-axis
> (if it crossed the $$-axis, then the quadratic would take
> negative values, which is impossible). Similarly, if $$ is negative,
> then the quadratic is always negative or $0$, so again it can't cross
> the $$-axis.

Comment: I'm happy you posted my comment as an answer. I too am supportive of this question, but I didn't want to post an answer given that it is likely to be closed and deleted. I don't like questions where it's clear I would just be doing somebody's homework, but this seems like a sincere question.